# Issue copying data from a PDF loaded in a iframe

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an internal tool where my team members need to copy some value from PDF into an input field. So I'm loading the pdf beside the input field using an iframe like this :

```
    <iframe style={{width:"40vw", height:"100vh"}}         src=""https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_0Jj3ba85sTBHir4F0BKJ2WurjYnCBg/preview""
          frameBorder="0"
        />
```

CTRL + C doesn't work. So copy value using right click. When I click the copy button and try pasting in the input field, the entire screen freezes. Even just by copying everything freezes.

Why is this happening? How can someone fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem not with code because in example all works fine without any freezes

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-glitter-5ghgqu?file=/src/App.js

If you want to hotkeys work, you should pass listener to iframe

```
window.myIframe = document.getElementById("iframe id").contentWindow;
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) { 
   myIframe.myKeydownEventHandler(evt); 
});
```